# How to locate symbols in a debug binary

Tags: c++, debugging, nm

I think `nm` is the tool, but none of the tutorials has helped me solve my problem. Let's say I have a debug built binary and a stack trace where it crashes. The stack trace says something like `foo() + 1500`.

I assume the number is bytes of offset in the binary. Correct?

However! There is nothing with precisely this address. The addresses of the symbols are NOT monotonically incrementing in `default` ,`sysv` nor `posix` format.

How can I determine where did the crash happen (before the end of which symbol)?

Comment: The number is offset from the start of the function `foo`. If you set the source path in gdb it should point you to actual code.

Comment: @Botje it's not a configuration issue. We are debugging from client logs. And currently handwaving away the fact that the provided offset is in the release version.

Comment: That is crucial information. Debug binaries differ from release binaries. Do you still have an un`strip`ed release binary that matches what you shipped or did you set aside debug symbols? Otherwise you get to reverse engineer your own released binary.